# Remove \n and everything afterward in mysql column

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like the example below. Sometimes there is <strike>an extra line</strike> a \n the column with info afterward that I do not need and I would like to remove it keeping only the first line. How would I remove these \n's and the data afterward in the column?

```
| column1          |
+------------------+
| name1            |
| useless info     |
+------------------+
| name2            |
+------------------+
| name3            |
+------------------+
```

My goal would be to end up with this:

```
| column1          |
+------------------+
| name1            |
+------------------+
| name2            |
+------------------+
| name3            |
+------------------+
```

Comment: two lines in a column?, what type is your column?.

Comment: Its a varchar, the reason why there are multiple lines is because there is a \n I am trying to get rid of the \n and everything afterward

Comment: oh i see , technically , you dont have two lines , so i Suggest you edit your post With The information you have told me.

Comment: ha, my fault on that, your right thanks for helping me clarify the question :)

Comment: all good, hope i help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
update your_table
set column1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1 , '\n', 1)
```

Comment: After Juan made me realize it wasnt really a 2nd line I was able to solve my problem with UPDATE my_table
    SET my_col = SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_col, '\n', 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
update 
t
set t.col1 = 
case 
 when locate("\n",col1) > 0 
  then left(col1,locate("\n",col1))
 else col1 end
from test t
```